# postgresql cant make users / roles

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-14.04, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am currently having trouble making roles for the postgresql this is what I already did but have made any progress since last night

```
simplybel@simplybel:~$ sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser $USER
sudo: unknown user: postgres
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
simplybel@simplybel:~$ sudo -u simplybel createuser --superuser $USER
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  role "simplybel" does not exist
simplybel@simplybel:~$ sudo -u postgres psql
sudo: unknown user: postgres
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
simplybel@simplybel:~$
```

I have been trying other stuff but haven't made any progress and I really need some help with how to make roles for this one

I am also getting this error when I try to

```
rails s
```

with my web app

[image]

any help will really be greatly appreciated and thanks

Answer (score 0):

your postgres server is stop, run postgres server by sudo service postgres start command.

**Edit:**
I think your posgresql install not done properly.

To install PostgreSQL in your ubuntu system follow below steps:

*Step 1:*

```
gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  010908312D230C5F      
gpg -a --export 010908312D230C5F | sudo apt-key add -
```

Update the package lists:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install the required version.

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4
```

*Step 2:*

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

Sample Output:

psql (9.4rc1)
Type "help" for help.

```
postgres=#
```

To exit from posgresql prompt, type \q in the psql prompt.

*Step 3:*

Now set "postgres" user password:

Login to postgresql prompt,

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

and set postgres password with following command:

```
postgres=# \password postgres 
Enter new password: 
Enter it again: 
postgres=# \q
```

*step 4:*

Create a New Super User from the psql Prompt:

```
postgres=# CREATE USER your_user_account
postgres-# WITH SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE
postgres-# PASSWORD 'user_Account_Password';
```

*Step 5*:
After configuring the password, edit the file /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf to use MD5 authentication with the postgres user:

```
local   all         postgres                          md5
```

Not you can restart the postgresql server

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Comment: hi i tried to start it with this  postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data   but apparently the pgsql/data is not there ,and only these ones are  |  bin  etc  foreman  games  heroku  include  lib man  sbin  share  src  |   so i really don't know how to start it, sadly i am a bit new with the postgresql so i am a bit confused here

Comment: E: Unable to locate package postgresql-9.4
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-9.4'
this is what shows when i do the -9.4 installation

Comment: did you run those commands? gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  010908312D230C5F      
gpg -a --export 010908312D230C5F | sudo apt-key add -

Comment: ill try this one first..  http://www.rogerpence.com/2015/01/02/install-postgres-9-4-on-ubuntu/